# Web Application Running on IIS Won't Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on Chrome and Safari on Mobile Devices

Tags: c#, .net, angular, iis

I have been struggling to figure out this bug as I don't have much experience with IIS, but I do believe the issues lies in the config somewhere.

**First of all, the setup:**

| Service/Framework | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Windows Server | 2016 |
| IIS | 10.0.14393.0 |
| App Back-end: .NET | 4.7.2 |
| App Front-end: Angular | 10.0.8 |

*Might be important* - the site is running on a subdomain, looks like this:
https://applicationName.domain.com

**The Issue**

Accessing the site on an android specifically **Chrome** will land you on the HTTP version of the page. Same thing goes for **Safari** on iOS. Other browsers on android such as Brave, Ecosia, Firefox and Opera all redirect to HTTPS. However, if the "s" is manually typed into the URL after HTTP the site will load.

**What has Been Done so Far**

URL Rewrite module has been installed for the IIS with the following config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I have also looked through the back-end code and we are using this:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

**Questions**

- Am I missing something really obvious?
- Is there something in Angular that would prevent Chrome and Safari from redirecting to HTTPS?
- Are there any other settings to IIS that I am not aware of?
- What would make Chrome and Safari to behave this way?

Any assistance or pointers would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: The IIS rule looks ok, just in case you can use Failed Request Tracing to double check if the rule is triggered: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules - even so UseHttpsRedirection should be sufficient on its own.  This is unlikely to be an Angular issue as the request for the URL & subsequent redirect should happen via headers before any content is loaded.

Comment: Thank you @AlexK. I will play around with setting up the tracing than test the site again to see what's going on. I was confused by the lack of effectiveness of UseHttpsRedirection, but I don't know how to investigate what it's doing.

Comment: @AlexK. I have implemented the Failed Request Tracing, but it doesn't seem to do much since when requesting the site it only loads about 5-10% then it says "This site can't be reached". So I just typed: appname.domain.com and that's what it does.

Comment: Some new development, so after implementing the tracing, the site now stops loading even in HTTPS on Chrome and Safari. The logger then creates the various XML documents but all of the ones I have checked respond with a 200, though nothing is visible anymore.

Comment: You will have to learn how to interpret the log files generated by FRT, and if you are not familiar with that you have to escalate to someone with the skills. Since the files usually contain confidential information, open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com and involve Microsoft support team.

Comment: @LexLi I am no expert by any means, but when the site is not even being hit via a http request there isn't much the logs can do for me. Either way, with some manual intervention this issue has been worked around.

Comment: If you happened to find a solution/workaround, you can post/accept your own answer below. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @LexLi True that, that's my bad. Just posted the workaround, it's poor but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Not much of a workaround per se, but the idea is that when we deploy the site, we'll just use a perma-link with https:// on SharePoint.

Then on mobile devices, IT will be able to push out an "app" with the link which will launch the web-app.
I know this is not ideal, but unless it's regularly expected that the user will type the address in manually, trying to figure out what the core issue would be a waste of time.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue at the moment. I added the same rule in IIS to force HTTPS and it works like a charm everywhere except on Android devices (on Chrome, Firefox or the default browser). The problem is : 80% of the people use my app on an Android tablet. I had to take all the tablets for the weekend to force all the shortcuts to https... Fortunately, that's only 10 tablets to update, but still, very weird problem. I'll continue searching and let you know if I find something.

Comment: I'll just add a comment as my problem is slightly different. I missed the line where you said that the HTTP version was served to the mobile devices. I didn't even have the HTTP version served. I used the FRT tool to check the rewrite actions... which didn't even execute. My problem was that I disabled the forwarding on port 80, as I wanted "SSL only". Oops. I thought my rule was working, and it was just my browsers using HTTPS as fallback. Except Chrome. If you explicitly type "http://" in any version of Chrome, it tries to load the HTTP version, and doesn't try HTTPS in case of failure...